# Why is this not a valid proof?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

A thread I saw recently has led me to believe that this is not a valid proof of the fact that for matrices $A$ and $B$, $AB=I\implies BA=I$.

Suppose $AB=I$. Then

$$A^{-1}AB=A^{-1}I$$

$$B=A^{-1}$$

$$BA=A^{-1}A$$

$$BA=I$$

what step is wrong in this? I assume $A$ has an inverse because $\det A\det B=\det AB=\det I=1$, so $\det A\neq 0$.

Comment: What leads you to believe this is invalid? I've seen exactly this proof in Schaum's Linear Algebra text.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3852/if-ab-i-then-ba-i

It is correct since the existence of a left inverse of a square matrix follows from the existence of a right inverse.

Comment: How do you know that $A$ has an inverse?  Once you do, then of course $B$ is it.  But the problem is to start with $AB=I$, not knowing that $A$ has an inverse, and conclude $BA=I$.  And from this it will follow that $B$ is the inverse of $A$.

Comment: Are you assuming that $A$, $B$, and $I$ are all $n\times n$ matrices? If that is not assumed, your statement is false and the proof is invalid since some of the products will be undefined. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Pretty sure he's assuming they're square. Else, this would have been obviously faulty to anyone.

Comment: The question I think you might be thinking about ([this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3852/if-ab-i-then-ba-i)) asks for proofs where there are some restrictions imposed (i.e. if you don't know about inverses).

Comment: @HasanSaad that's what's being proved here though? And to the others, yes I am assuming they're square and same dimension.

Comment: Also, thanks @Winther that helps

Comment: The first equality may be incorrect. There is no assumption that $A^{-1}$ exists

Comment: @sleevechen For a square matrix, the existence of a right inverse implies the existence of a left one.

As for OP, the proof here is that if $AB=I$ then $BA=I$ and this proof is completely valid. However, this "proof" misses the gist of the subject which is all about proving the existence of $A^{-1}$ first. If it were proved before, then this proof is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $A$ and $B$ are both square matrices of the same dimension, then your proof is certainly correct. However, $AB=I\not\Longrightarrow BA=I$  when $B$ and $A$ are not square, and your step of $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$ is wrong since $\det(A)$ and $\det(B)$ are not defined for non-square matrices. In general for a non-square matrix there are so-called left- and right-inverses, which may not be identical for a given matrix.

For example, let
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&1&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}, B=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$$
You can check $AB=I_\text{2x2}$ but $BA\neq I_\text{3x3}$